# WinForms override control box

Tags: winforms, controlbox

Does anyone know what it would take to override the look and feel of a WinForms Control Box?  I don't want to change the functionality of the buttons, I just want to change the color and the images.  Something similar to what [Instagrille](https://www.pokki.com/app/Instagrille) has done with their Instagram app for Windows.

Comment: Take a look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42460/479512) about changing Window Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control box is created by system. AFAIK, you cannot customize it. Although you can get rid of it and create your own. This will take some effort.

You will have to P/Invoke User32.dll and override WndProc to intercept windows messages.

Take a look are these articles to begin with. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11510/Add-Transparent-Menus-and-XP-Titlebar-Buttons-to-y) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10171/Adding-a-Minimize-to-tray-button-to-a-Form-s-capti) one.

Answer (score 1):

You may be better off porting your app to WPF. The level of control you're looking for comes "for free" in with the framework and is more future proof on the Windows platform. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111817/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-upgrade-a-large-c-sharp-winforms-app-to-wpf) is a good place to start, there are more good links [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2009/09/30/migrating-winforms-to-wpf-links-to-info.aspx).

If that's not an option, I think [danish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73568/danish) has you off to a start. I would be wary of attempting to extend WinForms too far beyond what it's meant to do, in my experience it can make for a headache in the future. Good luck.