# Looking for specific tutorial about WPF and WinForm

Tags: wpf, winforms

I remember once I found a nice online tutorial that showed how WPF works through nice exapamle of converting WinForm application into WPF. But I forgot link to it.

It was divided into multiple chapters. In first application was converted into WPF using WinForm "mindset" and then using specific technology of WPF (DataBinding, Controls, Templates) moved into (basicaly) MVVM, every chapter.

I tried searching, but every time I put WPF and WinForm in single query it shows only results about how to use WPF in WinForm or vice-versa or how to automaticaly convert WinForm into WPF.

Anyone can help??

Comment: See this previously asked question - it's not the same as yours but it's good info to know, that's related to your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313256/migrate-vb-net-2-0-winform-to-3-5-wpf  At one time, someone was working on a converter and there was a video, but it's no longer there so I assume this person abandoned the attempt.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/onoj/archive/2009/05/05/winforms-to-wpf-converter-sample.aspx

Comment: @David Starron - Sorry about not being clear. I was only looking for that specific tutorial. I dont really care about converting WinForm into WPF. And I actualy think such thing is sort of stupid, because you cant convert between so much different technologies like WF and WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was most likely my series: [From Windows Forms to WPF with MVVM](http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/).

Its basically an introduction to WPF from a Windows Forms perspective, showing how to transition to using MVVM architectural patterns, and why they provide a cleaner separation of concerns in your applications.

Comment: Yes, perfect. Thank you. I thought I found it on SO, but I couldnt find it here eihter.