# Implement WPF in WinForms after GUI design is done

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, user-interface

Is there a freeware library out there that will let me add the pretty WPF style graphics to an existing WinForms GUI project after-the-fact?  I know this will take some coding, so I'm asking is what is the best way (library or other) to make a WinForms GUI look pretty after it is already done.

Comment: Are you asking for a free skinning engine?

Comment: @SLaks - At this point I'm wondering what my options are/trying to find out what terms I should be Googling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps better to just convert it completely to WPF?

See: [Migrate VB.NET 2.0 Winform to 3.5 WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313256/migrate-vb-net-2-0-winform-to-3-5-wpf)

This post describes a tool written by Rob Relyea that looks through instantiation of your Win Forms controls, from InitializeComponent(), and generates XAML that should create an equivalent GUI.

Here's a CodePlex project that does something similar - [Windows Forms to Windows Presentation Foundation Converter](http://wf2wpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets)

Or you might look at something like [RadControls for WinForms](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx), from Telerik.  The idea is to leave everything in WinForms, but use their Win Forms controls, which have more of a WPF look and feel.